# Relation between chromatic number and average degree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

In my lecture notes, I read that a graph G which has vertices whose average degree is at most $d$ is not $d + 1$ colorable. This seems counter-intuitive to me.

I have tried examples with various graphs and cycles between them (so each vertex has degree 2 and hence average degree is 2) to find a case to support the claim. But I can't seem to find any.

Is this a mistake in the lecture notes or am I just not seeing something obvious?

Comment: I don't understand the claim. Is it saying that **every** graph $G$ with average degree $\le d$ has chromatic number $\gt d+1$? This is clearly false, any graph with no edges is a counterexample. Or is it saying that **there exists** a graph $G$ with average degree $\le d$ and chromatic number $\gt d+1$? This is trivially true; just take a graph of chromatic number $d+2$ and add enough isolated vertices to lower the average degree to $\le d$. I think you must have left out some assumption.

Comment: From the text:
An undirected graph $G$ with an average degree of at most $d$ cannot be coloured using $d+1$ colours. 
I think the text is referring to *any* graph G is not $d+1$ colourable if the average degree is at most $d$. 

As for your examples, a graph with no edges has an average degree 0 (d)and it's chromatic number is 1 (d+1) so it holds.

Comment: What do you mean, it holds? The text says "is ***not*** $d+1$ colourable"; if we set $d=0$ the graph with no edges **is** $d+1$ colourable. Moreover, "at most $d$" means $\le d$; a graph with no edges has average degree $0$ which is certainly "at most $500$", but it **is** $501$ colourable.

Comment: My bad, I got confused. But basically, the question boils down to: Can you colour a graph with d + 1 colours, if the average degree is at most d? I am sorry for making it confusing.

Comment: I already gave the counterexample: just take a graph of chromatic number $d+2$ and add enough isolated vertices to lower the average degree to $\le d$.

Answer (score 3):

There is no relationship between chromatic number and average degree.

On one hand, a graph with chromatic number $2$ can have arbitrarily large average degree. Just consider the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$: this has average degree $n$, but chromatic number $2$.

On the other hand, you can take any graph with chromatic number $k$ and reduce its average degree to an arbitrarily small number by adding many isolated vertices. If your starting graph has $n$ vertices, it has at most $\binom n2$ edges. By adding $t\binom n2 -n$ more isolated vertices, you reduce the average degree to at most $\frac{2\binom n2}{t \binom n2} = \frac2t$, which can be made as small as you want.

Comment: I see that intuitively, but could you provide a numerical example for the same? I have been searching for one but have been unable to find one.

Comment: I have edited my answer; does this help?